# How to use the like function to delete the table record?

Tags: sql

I have a problem to use the like % function to delete the table record, it cannot follow the **299-1_B** to delete the row in the table.

I am used below the sample code to delete:

```html
DELETE FROM filing_code_management WHERE folder_location LIKE '299-1_B%'
```

`table structure`

```html
no|folder_location
-- ------------------------------------
1   299_A/299-1_B/299-1-1_C/299-1-1-1_D
2   299_A/299-1_B
3   300_B/300-1_C
3   299_A/299-1_B/299-1-1_C/299-1-1-2_F
4   299_A/299-1_B/299-1-2_P/299-1-2-1_Q
```

If success to show the result, the result just show **300_B/300-1_C** record. Hope someone can guide me which part I am getting wrong.

Comment: What is the expected result and what do you get now? Please update the question with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below query,

```
DELETE FROM filing_code_management WHERE folder_location LIKE '%299-1_B%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find the pattern anywhere in the string:

```
folder_location LIKE '%299-1_B%'
```

Or perhaps:

```
folder_location LIKE '299-1_B%' OR folder_location LIKE '%/299-1_B%'
```

That said, you appear to be storing multiple values in a string.  That is bad, bad, bad.  You should have a separate table with one row per folder location, rather than forcing all of them into a single string.